Will there be a responsive datatable component soon?
This Reddit post Responsive Design for Datatable in LWC or other UI Suggestions? includes this quote with no links or details:

The salesforce data table was just redesigned to be responsive. The
component team shared it at TDX. I'd wait until you try it this
release before spending time creating your own or investing in a 3rd
party.

I had a brief look at the TDX recordings and the Summer '24 release notes but didn't find any mention of this. The classes slds-max-medium-table_stacked and slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal have been present for some time and do have an effect but are not well documented.
Will there be a responsive datatable component soon?
PS
Did some more Googling and found this session recording Elevate Your User Experience with Screen Flows | TrailblazerDX 2024. There the flow-specific Datatable is discussed, though not in the sense of working on small screens. So I suspect that the answer to this question posed here - a responsive lightning-datatable LWC - is No.

I take it you can't add the SLDS classes, in your usage, suggested in the answer for the other question you cited in your other answer on this topic?

Hi @PhilW, We have a Digital Experience that will have some work done for the mobile version soon. My recollection of the stacked view is that it is fairly basic, so if something new is coming out soon from SF, I'd at least like to understand what that might be. So looking for corroboration of the above comment and any details behind that. Otherwise we will likely end up building something.

Looks like the answer to this question is NO.
